# opening a div when a checkbox is checked and no of checkboxes are coming from database

Tags: php, jquery

```
http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=jquery-show-hide-div-using-checkboxes
```

here in the above link...there is a code where when you click on a checkbox , a div gets opened ...but the checkboxes are static .

now my no of checkboxes are coming from database like this :

```
            <?php
        $sql_activities="select * from tb_activities";
           $query_activities=mysql_query($sql_activities);

              $active=1;
        while($row_activities=mysql_fetch_array($query_activities))
          {

        ?>

   <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row_activities['activity_id']; ?>" name="activities<?php echo $active; ?>" ><?php echo " ".$row_activities["activity_name"]; ?>
            <?php    
             $active=$active+1;

            } ?>
```

now what i want is that if a five checkboxes are coming from database then five div should get opened as we click on each div....how can i achieve this ??

Comment: What's the relevant html that the browser sees? And have you made any attempt at all as yet, what happened? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: i dont understand how to open a div as the no of checkboxes are dependent on database value...so how to open a div when clicking on a checbox

Comment: you should create div also in while loop

Comment: ok i got how to create a div but how do i make it work in jquery part..like there i would need to give and id how will i do it for a div in a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**as you dont understand how to open a div** 
below is the working code that i have tested. so use this code and do your work.:)

```
$sql_activities="select * from tb_activities";
$query_activities=mysql_query($sql_activities);

$active=1;
while($row_activities=mysql_fetch_array($query_activities))
{

?>

   <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row_activities['activity_id']; ?>" name="activities<?php echo $active; ?>" class="" ><?php echo " ".$row_activities["activity_name"]; ?>
            <?php    
             $active=$active+1;

            } 



$sql_activities1="select * from tb_activities";
$query_activities1=mysql_query($sql_activities1);

$active1=1;
while($row_activities1=mysql_fetch_array($query_activities1))
{

?>

 <div class="<?php echo $row_activities1['activity_id']; ?> box">You have selected <strong><?php echo $row_activities1['activity_name']; ?> checkbox</strong> so i am here</div>


            <?php    
             $active1=$active1+1;

            } ?>            


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
           // if($(this).attr("value")=="red"){
                a=$(this).attr("value");
                $("."+a).toggle();

        });
    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    .box{
        padding: 20px;
        display: none;
        margin-top: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    </style>
```

**The mysql extension is deprecated**

Comment: this code made my day...thanks a lot for this help...:)

Answer (score 0):

I made some modifications to your code. I have given an id to the checkbox and also applied onclick on it. Also div will be created the number of times while loop will execute and these divs would be hidden. On clicking the checkbox,it will go to a function will allow corresponding div to open.

```
 while($row_activities=mysql_fetch_array($query_activities))
          {

        ?>

    <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row_activities['activity_id']; ?>"   name="activities<?php echo $active; ?>"  onclick="showdiv(<?php echo $active; ?>)"><?php echo " ".$row_activities["activity_name"]; ?>
    <div id="<?php echo $active; ?>" style="display:none;"></div>
            <?php  

             $active=$active+1;

            } ?>

    <script>
     function showdiv(id){
      $('#'+id).toggle();
     }
    </scritp>
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: yes it worked snehal but there is more thing in this code..now when i click on the checkbox a div appears but can we so something like this ..that if we click on checked box then the div should disppear ..something like this...when we click on a checkbox a div comes and if we again click on the same checkbox then the div should disappear

Comment: Yes we can do that.You only need to replace show() function in javascript function by toggle. I have edited my answer.